# pKa of acetic acid in pure NH3?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, physical-organic-chemistry

Acetic acid completely dissociates in liquid ammonia and I would like to know the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value for the acid in that solvent. Can anybody point me to a reference?

Comment: I'm not sure such reference exists, but maybe... who knows. One thing is that's a bit obscure solvent, second that acetic acid is strong in something like that and it's difficult to estimate pKa of strong acids.

Comment: Is acetic acid soluble in liquid ammonia?

Comment: Yes, it is soluble as the question implies.